# Get timezone aware datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

How would I do the following to get a UTC datetime object, so django doesn't complain about `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:808: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2015-02-11 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.`
 ?

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.date(2014,1,1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your example, you should use `datetime` and specify the tzinfo argument:

```
timezone.datetime(2014, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.UTC())
```

You may also be interested in Django's `make_aware` function:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is a string with no timezone information, just append a literal `"Z"` to your string. This indicates zero offset from UTC time.

Comment: In that case I receive: `ValidationError: [u"'2015-02-11Z' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
`

Comment: Ah, my bad. I thought your input had date and time. After a bit of digging, I've found a config setting in Django, `USE_TZ`, which should be set `False`.